# Unable to revert bucket

Tags: buckets

Using Sitecore 8.2
I have mistakenly clicked on `Bucket` for the `sitecore` node. When I click on `Revert`, it throws an error every time.

[image]

> An error occured
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at
>   Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketProvider.ProcessChildren(Item item,
>   Language language) at
>   Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketProvider.UnbucketItem(Item
>   contextItem) at
>   Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketProvider.UnbucketItem(Item
>   contextItem) at
>   Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketProvider.UnbucketItem(Item
>   contextItem) at
>   Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketProvider.UnbucketItem(Item
>   contextItem) at
>   Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketProvider.UnbucketItem(Item
>   contextItem) at
>   Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketProvider.UnbucketItem(Item
>   contextItem) at
>   Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.UnBucket.UnbucketProcessor.StartProcess(Item
>   contextItem) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj) at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args) at (Object , Object[]
>   ) at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea you're going to have to revert that manually.

In Content Editor, navigate to `/sitecore`, make sure View -> Standard Fields is enabled, then uncheck the `Is Bucket` field and clear `Bucket parent reference` (if one is set).

If the Content Editor gives you grief over this, do it via the `/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx` tool.

Comment: That worked. But there is still that - "There are hidden items in this container" message.

Comment: try collapsing the Sitecore node and expanding again. Alternatively do a hard refresh of the page.

Comment: Did all that & a logout too

Comment: Try checking "Buckets" checkbox (next to Standard Fields) on the View. See what items are being hidden.

Comment: I can see some custom items. though unchecked hidden items. It's no harm though but it wasn't like this before.

Comment: Some items might have been bucketed when you initially clicked. You may have to go through the steps you did for /sitecore, for these items as well.